# How to restrict a User from deleting a particular field but able to update it?

Tags: security, permission-sets

I'm having a requirement where a user can update a particular field but once entered values into that field shouldn't be deleted. Can I acheive this using standard salesforce functionality without writing any code. Help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a validation rule, something like this:

```
ISBLANK(Field) && NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(Field)))
```

There's no "no-code" solution, but a validation rule is about as close as you'll get.

Comment: by doing this I guess a user can delete the previous value wright ? but my requirement is A value once entered and saved in the field shouldn't be deleted if the user comes and edits the record.

Comment: @EagerinSf This validation rule prevents making the field blank again. You could also specify if the value was previously not blank it can no longer be changed. It really depends on your exact purpose.

Answer (score -1):

ISCHANGED(  field  ) && TEXT(PRIORVALUE( Field )) != ''

i guess this will resolve your issue.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE rahul. You may not realize it, but the question you've posted an answer to has an accepted answer that is accurate, correct and complete. It is also not a "guess". I recommend you visit the [Help] to better understand how our Forum works.